# Footer at not proper position for parallax

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a parallax but before using any js to create the real "parallax", I'm trying to position footer at the bottom so it comes out like this below. Why is this happening and how could I fix it to work only with css? Sorry if the images are not clear!

[image]

**But footer is coming out in a weird way like:**
[image]

**Here's my css and html.**

```css
.about {
  height: 300vh;
  display: flex;
}

.about-title {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.about-pages {
  width: 50%;
}

.about-pages div {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.about-pages div>p {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lemonchiffon
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: powderblue
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lavender
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: moccasin
}

footer {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1> Go-Out-To-Eat. Simplest way to enjoy.</h1>
</header>
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-title">
    <h2> All you can eat, cheaper and faster. </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="about-pages">
    <div>
      <h2> Page 1 </h2>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 2 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 3 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 4 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <h2> Contact now, Tel) 1234567 </h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: why don't u use flex-basis for your inner display flex width's?

Answer (score 1):

It had to do with the `.about` class where you declared `300vh`.

The footer couldn't go any lower so it had to overlap with `Page 4`. I have also changed the height of your divs and the footer so you can see the snippet better. Without changing any of your css and removing `Page 4`, it fixed your problem itself as well.

Make sure you **Run code snippet** to fullpage to see the real result.

```css
.about {
  display: flex;
}

.about-title {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.about-pages {
  width: 50%;
}

.about-pages div {
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.about-pages div>p {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lemonchiffon
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: powderblue
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lavender
}

.about-pages div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: moccasin
}

footer {
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-title">
    <h2> All you can eat, cheaper and faster. </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="about-pages">
    <div>
      <h2> Page 1 </h2>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 2 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 3 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3> Page 4 </h3>
      <p> Random Text Generated. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <h2> Contact now, Tel) 1234567 </h2>
</footer>
```